# Placing QWidgets at specified coordinates?

Tags: c++, css, qt, graphics

**Context:** I'm making Risk (the popular board game) in C++/Qt, and I've run into a problem. I decided to make the map interactive by placing buttons on every country, which could then be clicked on. After some experimenting, I've subclassed QGraphicsPixmapItem for the buttons, and stuck them inside a QGraphicsScene and a QGraphicsView. I've made the world map a background image via CSS, so that buttons could be overlaid without much hassle.

**My problem:** I want to place those buttons *at specific coordinates*. (If it matters, those coordinates would be absolute.) All of the interfaces that I've made so far, I've done in code - I'm not familiar with the Qt Designer, so I'm looking for *a function* or *set of functions* that'd let me place my buttons (more or less) where I want them.

**What I've tried:** I looked in the documentation, but couldn't find a function that let me control where items were placed, just ones that organized items in various ways - columns, horizontal boxes, vertical boxes, etc.
When I designed QWidgets before, I'd done so by placing buttons, other widgets, etc. in QLayouts, but there don't seem to be layouts that allow me the control I'd like. The only one I can see that'd do something similar, is QGridLayout, and experiments with that so far haven't worked the way I wanted them to - the buttons don't get anywhere near the edges of the map, no matter how many columns or rows I add.

The easiest solution would be giving up and placing the buttons beside the map, of course, but that's a last-ditch solution.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Added example source code, for clarity.

```
QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout;
TerritoryButton* test = new TerritoryButton(QPixmap("img.png"));
TerritoryButton* test2 = new TerritoryButton(QPixmap("img.png"));
QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene;
QGraphicsScene* scene2 = new QGraphicsScene;
scene->addItem(test);
scene2->addItem(test2);
QGraphicsView* view = new QGraphicsView(scene);
QGraphicsView* view2 = new QGraphicsView(scene2);

layout->addWidget(view);
layout->addWidget(view2);
setLayout(layout);
setFixedSize(1000, 512);
```

Comment: *I've subclassed QGraphicsPixmapItem for the buttons, and stuck them inside a QGraphicsScene and a QGraphicsView* - Do you mean you have a GraphicsScene and QGraphicsView per button, or all the buttons together, in a single scene? Note that an example of source code would be really useful!

Comment: @TheDarkKnight I mean I've got a Scene and a View per button. It's probably far from the most efficient solution, but the others I've tried don't work as well - QLabel with a Pixmap doesn't register the click, for some reason, and just using QPixmaps didn't work for me. I'll add some source code for the others who might stumble across the question.

Comment: Ouch! I thought as much and there lies your problem. I suggest researching QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene. It's generally used without widgets (though they can be embedded via a proxy). One would normally create a single QGraphicsScene and add QGraphicsItems or QGraphicsObjects. The scene is viewed through a QGraphicsView. You can built the whole game with these classes. Take a look at the Qt examples and there are various tutorials which I'm sure you can find on the Internet.

Comment: You're right, that seems like a much better solution. I'd tried putting several buttons in one scene, but that made them overlap - a problem which is easily solvable, now that I know of the setPos function. Thanks, you've been a big help.

Answer (score 0):

`QGraphicsPixmapItem` inherits `QGraphicsItem`, so you can call `setPos(x, y)` (after inserting the pixmap item into the scene with `addItem`).

> `void QGraphicsItem::setPos(const QPointF &pos)`
> Sets the position of the item to pos, which is in parent coordinates. For
> items with no parent, pos is in scene coordinates.
>
> The position of the item describes its origin (local coordinate (0, 0)) in parent coordinates.